# What kinds of stories would people from a forest moon tell about their "moon"?

Tags: culture, moons

Here on earth, the moon is this big white thing that lights the world and hangs in the sky. Every culture on the Earth has incorporated the moon into some of their legends. Sometimes as a woman, sometimes as a man, sometimes as a major god, sometimes as a lesser god. However, on an forested moon of Earth-like description, circling a blue and green super Earth of 3x the size, the stories would be different  for no other reason than because they have no big white ball in the sky.

Clearly the stories they tell their children will be radically different than the ones we tell our children.  Specifically, how might their creation myths be different from Earth's with their giant blue-green super Earth as their "moon"?

Comment: I realize that this could be rather broad, if so, I'll try to narrow it down some more.

Comment: I wonder if ancient cultures were able to figure out that the moon caused tides, or if people in this scenario would make the connection. If so, that could cause some interesting theological constructs.

Comment: Little confused here since Endor is a habitable moon orbiting a gas giant.  Are you talking about A) creation myths of beings living on a super-earth with a habitable moon, B) creation myths of beings living on Endor orbiting a gas giant, or C) creation myths of beings living on Endor orbiting a habitable super earth?  (Guessing C but want to clarify for sure).  Also, is your moon tidally locked?

Comment: Removed the confusing Endor reference.  The moon is not tidally locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endor is a gas giant, so it's not likely that it would have inhabitants on it, at least not ones anything like us.

However, the question can be addressed by imagining a forest moon where our moon is. Imagine a moon up there with an atmosphere and trees and other living things. From earth, it would probably look like a mini-earth floating up there. It might cause cultures to assume that earth is not the center of the universe (as almost all cultures understandably did in ancient times), but rather one of many worlds. It may also have led to a much faster development of spacefaring, as the development of telescopes would have revealed the existence of fauna on the planet with a high degree of culture and sophistication (i.e., Ewoks, who have built homes among the trees and developed a lot of human characteristics).

Answer (score 1):

The ultra-moon would be Heaven. At the beginning of time, humanity lived on Ultramoon. A giant name (let's say Wally) cast out humanity when they entered his forbidden garden three times (cast out on third entry).

If a person is a good person (by Wally the giant's standards) they will go to Ultramoon when they die. All dogs go to Ultramoon.

Just imagine if there is an industrial-age civilization on Ultramoon. The city lights at night will enhance the belief in the Ultramoon after life.